# how to discard changes made to all linq tables?

Tags: c#, database, linq, datacontext

I would like to discard all changes made to linq tables (this means -- I use linq, and data are changed on client side, the data on server are intact). How to do this?

**EDIT: problem partially solved**

http://graemehill.ca/discard-changes-in-linq-to-sql-datacontext/

It works as long as you don't use transaction. When you do and you use mixed "mode" for a record, there is a problem:

```
begin trans
insert a record
update inserted record
commit trans
```

When you update record as above Linq counts it as updated record, and in case of exception you have two actions -- transaction is rolled back and data on Linq side are discarded. On discard changes Linq tries to fetch it from the database (discard for update means refetching data for a record), but since all changes were rolled back, there is no records for update.

### The question

How to improve DiscardChanges method in a smart general way to work with transactions. Or how to change the workflow of transactions/discard-submitchanges to make all those work together?

Those are not smart solutions:

1. refetching *all* data
2. recreating connection to DB (because it leads to (1))

Answer (score 6):

To add to what Johannes said, I think the confusion here stems from thinking of the `DataContext` as something similar to a `DataSet`.  It isn't.

A "table" in a `DataContext` is like a hint on how to retrieve a specific type of data entity from the database.  Unlike a `DataSet`, the `DataContext` does not actually "contain" data, it simply tracks the discrete entities you've pulled out of it.  If the `DataContext` disappears (is disposed), the entities are still valid, they are simply detached.  This is different from a `DataSet` where the individual `DataTables` and `DataRows` are essentially bound to their containers and cannot outlive them.

In order to use the `Refresh` method of a `DataContext`, you need to use it on an actual entity or collection of entities.  You can't "Refresh" a `Table<T>` because it's not actually a physical table, it's just a kind of reference.

Changes to entities connected to a `DataContext` are only persisted when you call the `SubmitChanges` method.  If you dispose of the `DataContext`, there is absolutely no way that the changes can persist unless you manually reattach the detached entities to a new `DataContext`.

Comment: +1: This can be surprisingly tricky to get right.  I was once building a Linq to Sql app and I mentally "knew" this, yet I still painted myself into a corner when trying to create a good user experience in data entry dialogs that allowed the user to cancel changes.  I like the ideas behind Linq to Sql, but I'm not sold on the execution in part because of the difficulty of doing this sort of task.

Answer (score 3):

Simply discard the current DataContext without calling SubmitChanges() and get a new one.

Example:

```
DataContext myOldDc = new DataContext();
```

Comment: There is 1 problem with this and 2 issues. Let's start from issues:
a) efficiency -- I have to specify connection string for new data context, and it means it actually connects to the database again -- and this is not for free
b) side effects -- C# GC is not deterministic, which means old data context can still live, I am not sure what effect it would have with transactions

And the problem:
a) I already passed the data context to several helper classes, when I change the data context I am doing it locally, and the helper classes when doing Submit they submit data I wanted to get rid off

Comment: Don't assume that resubmitting the connection string will actually create a new connection unless you've verified that through Reflector.  The connstring could just as easily be a key to a dictionary of connection pools, e.g.